# Trace of power of symmetric matrices

Tags: symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be real symmetric matrices. Suppose that for all integers $k\ge1$ we have 
$$
{\rm tr}((A+B)^k)={\rm tr}(A^k) + {\rm tr}(B^k).
$$
 Prove that then, $AB=0$ (the converse is clearly true as $A$ and $B$ are symmetric). Note: this question is NOT a duplicate of a resembling question asked on this forum. We do NOT suppose that

$$
{\rm tr}((xA+yB)^k)=x^k{\rm tr}(A^k) +y^k{\rm tr}(B^k).
$$
for all $x,y$ real, but ONLY for $x=y=1$.

Comment: Do you want to see a more general proof. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583273/how-prove-this-two-symmetric-matrices-ab-0)

Comment: The result is stronger - no x or y in my question.

Comment: there is. In fact x=y=1 in your question.

Comment: @Kumar Nilesh yes, but the linked question has as a part of the hypothesis the requirment, that the equality holds for all $x,y$, not only the particular $x=y(=1)$.

Comment: Which is the field / ring of definition for the entries of the matrices?

Comment: These are real matrices, so they have real eigenvalues and an orthornormal basis of eigenvectors